# How to build a custom bottomNavigationBar in flutter with a centered button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have tried so much to build this **bottomNavigationBar** with the **curve** and **space between icons**.
Cannot figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this package: [convex_bottom_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar).

The notch shape can be customized by writing a class that extending `NotchedShape` and implementing `getOuterPath` that contains the logic for the notch curve. Check this out to know exact implementation [convex_shape.dart](https://github.com/hacktons/convex_bottom_bar/blob/master/lib/src/convex_shape.dart)

To have a green icon at the bottom:

```
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';

Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
    items: [
      TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Left'),
      TabItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.green,), activeIcon: new Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.green,) title: 'Middle'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.message, title: 'Right'),
    ],
    initialActiveIndex: 2,//optional, default as 0
    onTap: (int i) => print('click index=$i'),
  )
);
```

Comment: The problem is, you can't make a default color for the middle whether it is active or not! I need the middle button to stay green all the time

Comment: Why don't you specify the color for the icon and set that icon in the tabItem for the middle tab. To keep it same when active or not, just pass the same icon as activeIcon too

Comment: Updated with a snippet. Hope that is what you are expecting. Note here that according to package implementation, by default `activeIcon` is equal to `icon`, if it is not supplied. So you should be able to achieve what you want (fixed green color) without `activeIcon`

Answer (score 1):

```
 floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        elevation: 2.0,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        notchMargin: 5,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              currentIndex: 0,
              onTap: (int index) {},
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.radio), label: 'A'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Check this code.

Comment: Perfect, how to make the notch above the button?? as you can see it should be at the top and show a curve!